# Dual of intersection of vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

The precise question I am trying to answer is the following: if we have a (finite dimensional) vector space $V$ and two endomorphisms $T, S: V \to V$, is it possible to describe the dual space of $\mathrm{Ker}(T) \cap \mathrm{Ker}(S)$ in terms of the cokernels of the dual maps?

This is coming from the fact that we have a canonical isomorphism $\mathrm{Ker}(T)^{\vee} \cong \mathrm{Coker}(T^\vee)$, where $T^\vee: V^\vee \to V^\vee$ is the dual map to $T$. I know that the intersection may be described as a Cartesian diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Ker}(T) \cap \mathrm{Ker}(S) @>>> \mathrm{Ker}(T)\\
@VVV \ulcorner @VVV\\
\mathrm{Ker}(S) @>>> V,
\end{CD}
so dualizing gives a co-Cartesian diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
(\mathrm{Ker}(T) \cap \mathrm{Ker}(S))^\vee @<<< \mathrm{Coker}(T^\vee)\\
@AAA \ulcorner @AAA\\
\mathrm{Coker}(S^\vee) @<<< V^\vee.
\end{CD}

However, I don't know how to interpret this without an ambient space (I believe that in the presence of an ambient space pushouts correspond to sums of vector subspaces).

Comment: What do you mean by "ambient space"? For vector spaces, the canonical pushout of the diagram $$\begin{CD} @.B\\@.@AAfA\\C@<<g<A \end{CD}$$ is the quotient $(B \oplus C)/\{(f(x),-g(x)) : x \in A\}$. Hence $\newcommand{\coker}{\operatorname{coker}} \newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$ $$(\ker(T) \cap \ker(S))^\vee \cong \big( \!\coker(T^\vee) \oplus \coker(S^\vee) \big)/\{(f+\im(T), -f+\im(S)) : f \in V^\vee\}.$$